# Difference between mysql cache and memcached

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching

I have 1 mysql table which is controlled strictly by admin. Data entry is very low but query is high in that table. Since the table will not change content much I was thinking to use [mysql query cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-qc.php) with PHP but got confused (when i googled about it) with `memcached`.

- What is the basic difference between `memcached` and `mysqlnd_qc` ?
- Which is most suitable for me as per below condition ?
- I also intend to extend the same for autcomplete box, which will be suitable in such case ?

My queries will return less than 30 rows mostly of very few bytes data and will have same `SELECT` queries. I am on a single server and no load sharing will be done. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your query is always the same, i.e. you do `SELECT title, stock FROM books WHERE stock > 5` and your condition never changes to `stock > 6` etc., I would suggest using MySQL Query Cache.

Memcached is a key-value store. Basically it can cache anything if you can turn it into key => value. There are a lot of ways you can implement caching with it. You could query your 30 rows from database, then cache it row by row but I don't see a reason to do that here if you're returning the same set of rows over and over. The most basic example I can think of for memcached is:

```
// Run the query
$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT title, stock FROM books WHERE stock > 5");

// Fetch result into one array
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

// Put the result into memcache.
$memcache_obj->add('my_books', serialize($rows), false, 30);
```

Then do a `$memcache_obj->get('my_books');` and unserialize it to get the same results.

But since you're using the same query over and over. Why add the complication when you can let MySQL handle all the caching for you? Remember that if you go with memcached option, you need to setup memcached server as well as implementing logic to check if the result is already in cache or not, or if the records have been changed in the database.

I would recommend using MySQL query cache over memcached in this case.

One thing you need to be careful with MySQL query cache, though, is that your query must be **exactly the same**, no extra blank spaces, comments whatsoever. This is because MySQL does no parsing to determine compare the query string from cache at all. Any extra character somewhere in the query means a different query.

Peter Zaitsev explained very well about MySQL Query Cache at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/, worth taking a look at it. Make sure you don't need anything that MySQL Query Cache does not support as Peter Zaitsev mentioned.

Comment: Checked that link. I finally stuck with Mysql cache example at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php Since my needs are simple avoiding complex `memcached` for time being (not a server guy anyways). What I could make out is Memcached can be used for more complex caching (different results/different ways) Only one more doubt. I hope that mysql cache will be available for various users/sessions and not per user/sessions and hence the cached result will persist for other user queries with same `SELECT` query !

Comment: Since the cache happens on MySQL, it shouldn't be dependent on your users anyway. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html "The query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another client."

Answer (score 2):

If the queries run fast enough and does not really slows your application, do not cache it. With a table this small, MySQL will keep it in it's own cache. If your application and database are on the same server, the benefit will be very small, maybe even not measurable at all.

So, for your 3rd question, it also depends on how you query the underlying tables. Most of the time, it is sufficient to let MySQL cache it internally. An other approach is to generate all the possible combinations and store these, so mysql does not need to compute the matching rows and returns the right one straight away.

As a general rule: build your application without caching and only add caches for things that do not change often if a) the computation for the resultset is complex and timeconsuming or b) you have multiple application instances calling the database over a network. In those cases caching results in better performance.

Also, if you run PHP in a web server like Apache, caching inside your program does not add much benefit as it only uses the cache for the current page. An external cache (like memcache)- is then needed to cache over multiple results.

Comment: For my autocomplete textbox I will cache all possible combination for 2-3 alphabets, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the basic difference between memcached and mysqlnd_qc ?

There is rather nothing common at all between them

> Which is most suitable for me as per below condition ?

mysql query cache

> I also intend to extend the same for autcomplete box, which will be suitable in such case ?

Sphinx Search

Comment: Thankyou for replying but aren't they both caching mysql query ?? For 3rd question I am doing ajax call for every alphabet of city was trying to cache such static sql queries in my autocomplete (Sphinx is not for me)